# how to choose a specific item from groups with a use of variable in ansible

Tags: jenkins, ansible

So I have a provision file with content as follow:

```
[dev-hosts]
dev-host-1
dev-host-2
dev-host-3

[tst-hosts]
tst-host-1
tst-host-2
tst-host-3
```

==========

In jenkins I choose an environment (dev, tst) and I need a playbook to get access to a specific item from the groups. I tried an expression as follows:

`{{ groups[\"{{ env }}-hosts\"][0] }}` << this gives me unexpected char u'\\' error and fails the job

`{{ groups["{{ env }}-hosts"][0] }}` << this on the other hand results in 'dict object' has no attribute '{{ env }}-hosts'"}

I went through ansible documentation but found no answer. How can I end up with 'dev-host-1' or any other item from the groups having the {{ env }} variable provided in Jenkins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Another rule is ‘moustaches don’t stack’.
> We often see this:
>
> ```yaml
> {{ somevar_{{other_var}} }}
> ```
>
> The above DOES NOT WORK as you expect, if you need to use a dynamic variable use the following as appropriate:
>
> ```yaml
> {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['somevar_' + other_var] }}
> ```

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names*</sup>

If you want to have a variable concatenated with a string inside a moustaches block, use the Jinja operator designed for this: `~`

<sub>Mind that the `+` sign would also work but migh have side effect, as explained in Jinja documentation:</sub>

> `+` Adds two objects together. Usually the objects are numbers, but if both are strings or lists, you can concatenate them this way.
> This, however, is not the preferred way to concatenate strings! For string concatenation, have a look-see at the `~` operator. `{{ 1 + 1 }}` is `2`.

<sup>*Source: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#math*</sup>

For example:

```yaml
"{{ groups[env ~ '-hosts'][0] }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from [@β.εηοιτ.βε](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66492484/13968097) perfectly addresses the question, but I am adding an answer to provide a different perspective.

As per Ansible [best practices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html):

> You can keep your production environment separate from development, test, and staging environments by using separate inventory files or directories for each environment. This way you pick with `-i` what you are targeting. Keeping all your environments in one file can lead to surprises!

So *if you can maintain* two different folders, i.e. `dev/hosts` and `tst/hosts` (which also helps in organizing `group_vars/` and `host_vars/` by the way), you will be able to target the hosts with `-i dev/hosts` or `-i tst/hosts`. It may also simplify the requirements  for using variables such as `{{ env }}` for targeting the hosts.

Answer (score 0):

(as an addendum)

Simplify the code by creating the selected list, e.g.

```yaml
    my_hosts: "{{ groups[env ~ '_hosts'] }}"
```

Then you can simply refer to the list *my_hosts*, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    my_hosts: "{{ groups[env ~ '_hosts'] }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: my_hosts.1
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e env=tst

PLAY [all] **********************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************
ok: [dev-host-1] => 
  my_hosts.1: tst-host-2
```